# document.write doesnt work, but console.log does

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, document.write

So I am creating an array out of the events created by a certain user on facebook, I have all the API stuff working and everything but I cant document.write it for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
for( var i = 0 ; i < response.length ; i++ ) 
{
    if (response[i]['eid'] > 0)
    {
        document.write([response[i]['name']] + '</br>' + response[i]['description']),
        console.log([response[i]['name']] + '</br>' + response[i]['description']);
    }
}
```

When I log it, its fine, but I cant actually display it on the page. alert()'ing it also works.

Any ideas how I can spit these variables out?

Comment: you try putting a semicolon at the end of your first statement instead of a comma?

Comment: @Jason That still doesn't explain why this isn't working. The comma operator will evaluate each of its operands, so both functions must be run.

Comment: Where is this code being run? In a function?

Comment: @David I know. But it's worth a shot :)

Comment: How do you know it's not working?  There are any number of reasons why markup appended to the end of the document body might not be visible.  As such, `document.write()` is not very good for debugging.  Why not set the HTML of a container element instead?  Then you can be sure the container is visible.

Comment: @Jason the comma is fine. Some minifiers actually replace semicolons with commas for sequences of expression statements.  (Not saying it's *good*, just that it's not a problem.)

Comment: I know what a comma does. I'm just saying that it's possible that it may be causing the issue. As you said, it's not _good_...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call document.write after page load, it rewrites the current page which doesn't contain the returned data or loop iterating over that data. Since you are using the FB API, Im guessing this is being run after page load. Try using a client-side templating solution to render all of that data. That way you won't have to do a bunch of string concatenation to create the HTML for your data.

Comment: How do I go upon doing that? All I have access to on the servers I am working with is ASP Classic.

Comment: That's only if his script is contained in the body, it should still work if it's in the head. Also, if the page isn't setup properly as html, document.write may not work, or will work unexpectedly.

Comment: No, it does not work if it is in the <head>. I just tested it out. His Facebook API request, whether via AJAX or JSONP is asynchronous, so when it comes back, the page load event has already fired and when document.write is called, it will rewrite the page.

Comment: @RickBross Try the Handlebars client-side templating library: http://handlebarsjs.com/. In short, you define templates in script blocks with a type of something other than text/javascript, include the library source, and call some functions that the library provides to replace template holders with actual data and it returns a new HTML string that you can insert into the DOM.

Comment: using document.write does not replace the entire page, it replaces the body. Try doing a window load event, set a timer for like 3 seconds inside of that, then do a loop that uses document.write. If what you're saying is correct, the loop wouldn't be able to go past the first iteration, however it does

Comment: I think it does replace all the elements on the page. I just did a demo where I set the title tag, executed an AJAX request and when it finishes, the document.write is executed and the title tag is no longer in the DOM. The old title value is still in my browser tab but no longer in the DOM

Comment: I ended up figuring out, ill post my code up top if anyone wants to see.

Comment: Ok so I was wrong, it does overwrite the entire document, however a simple example will show that scripts that have already executed and set variables in memory don't just disappear when the text of the document is overwritten. Anything you set in the global object (window), whether it's functions or variables are still there.

Answer (score 0):

If the sole purpose of the page is to display the results of the FB api call, then as long as your page is setup as valid HTML and all of your javascript is contained in the head part of the document, document.write should work. document.write is generally only ever used before the page loads, and within the body. Once the page loads, the entire body section of the document is written over and replaced. So if any of your scripts are within the body, it will be replaced also.

A much better alternative in my opinion is to have a div and populate the div with the results.

HTML:

```
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var results = "";

for( var i = 0 ; i < response.length ; i++ ) 
{
    if (response[i]['eid'] > 0)
    {
        results += response[i]['name'] + '</br>' + response[i]['description'];
        console.log(response[i]['name'] + '</br>' + response[i]['description']);
    }
}

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results;
```

Edit: My explanation above is wrong, document.write does rewrite the entire document if used after the page loads. My solution above is still 100% valid.

The accepted answer above isn't 100% correct... the code below clearly demonstrates that even when the document is overwritten, at the very least, functions and variables already set in the global object (window) are not lost, and they still run. So if you loop through data that is already set, it will still run and display the results, so there is more to the issue than just the javascript being overwritten.

Try this out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>hi</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                // this runs 3 seconds after the page loads, so after the first iteration
                // the entire document is erased and overwritten with 'hi',
                // however this loop continues to run, and write() continues to execute,
                // showing that the javascript still exists and operates normally.
                write();
        }, 3000);
    };

    // this variable will still exist after the page is overwritten
    window.someVar = "foo";

    // this function still exists and executes after the page is overwritten
    function write() {
        document.write("hi");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <b>hello</b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```